# Determining odd/even functions

Tags: calculus, functions

can someone please tell me if I did these steps correctly? I just want to make sure I have the right intuition. Thank you.

Let $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \sin(n\pi x/ 2),$$ where $$a_n = 2\int_0^2 x^4 \sin(n\pi x/ 2)dx.$$

i. Is $f(x)$ even, odd, or neither? What is the period?

$\textbf{Solution:}$ Since we can denote $a_n$ as $$a_n = \frac{2}{l} \int_0^l f(x) \sin(n\pi x/l) dx$$ where $l = 2$ then we have that $f(x) = 2x^4$ and this is even with period = 2.

ii. Find $f(-9)$ and $f(6)$

$\textbf{Solution:}$ $f(-9) = 2(-9)^4 = 13122$ and $f(6) = 2592.$

Comment: Wouldn't the Fourier series for $2x^4$ also have cosine terms? Are the individual functions in the sum defining $f$ odd or even? What can you deduce about $f$ from that?

Comment: Not sure on $i$.  For 2 note that $f$ is periodic,  with period 2,  so you need to find the representive value inside $[0,2]$ for $-9$ and $6$ before evaluating

Comment: @Alan I am not sure about i. anymore as well

Comment: @GregMartin I thought the cosine terms would vanish?

Comment: Why would they vanish for $f(x)=2x^4$? Have you computed some of them to see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is flawed.  First $sin(-u)=-sin(u)$ for any real $u$, so the series, as the sum of odd functions, is odd.  The period is $2l$.  Note that you start with $l=2$.